# How to setup PyCharm Settings Repository

Tags: python, pycharm

I'm trying to setup a [Settings Repository](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/synchronizing-and-sharing-settings.html) in PyCharm, but I'm running into some issues. Basically I want to save a setting to the `repository`, and then pull that change. I don't want any time anyone makes any modifications to their local area for that to affect the repo. I am on windows using `git`. Here is what I did:

1. Create directory at C:\foo
2. Export settings file `File | Export Settings...` -> Select all ->  C:\foo\settings.jar
3. Create `git` repo at C:\foo using MINGW64. `cd C:\foo` -> `git init`
4. Add settings to `git` repo. `git add .` -> `git commit -m "bar"`
5. Setup Settings Repository `Settings | Tools | Settings Repository | +` -> C:\foo
6. ...? `File | Settings Repository` -> `Overwrite Remote`

At this point to my knowledge the repository is setup. Now I try making a local modification, and pull what was stored in the repo.

7. Change something locally -> `Settings | Tools | External tools` -> delete something
8. Restart (since `Auto Sync` is turned on by default).

When PyCharm starts up again, **EVERYTHING** goes away as if I never had PyCharm settings. I was able to eventually revert things back because I had backups of my settings.jar file.

Does anyone have any idea of what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4):

The only solution I found that worked for me was to use a `github` repository as described [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/sharing-your-ide-settings.html) This link walks through how to do things. Essentially you want a repo with nothing in it and point PyCharm to that. However, I still ran into a lot of issues and bugs with the way it is currently implemented which resulted in losing all settings multiple times with varying levels of difficulty in getting them back (I really thought I had lost everything despite having backups of my settings file).

In its current state I don't recommend it for professional work.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your are saving your settings twice.  The .jar file is independent of using the repository.  Try creating an empty repository and then clicking `File | Settings Repository -> Overwrite Remote`.

I created an empty (private) repository at [bitbucket.org](https://bitbucket.org) and saved my PyCharm settings with no issues.