# How does one share general pycharm setting from previous pycharm set up?

Tags: pycharm

I have the re-ocurring issue that whenever I have a new laptop at work I need to manually put all my old setting from pycharm manually.

As a motivating example I have to put the custom split down and side panes (+ remote deployment configs). For the panes split it's mainly because I don't see pycharm having default setting.

Is there a way to import all of this painlessly? e.g. importing a some pycharm special config file or something?

For the specific split pane I am sure one can do it by following these instructions but would like to make my process my robust (e.g. I might want to import other things besides split pane e.g. deployment configs, perhaps python envs, or
as much as possible? Varying degrees of import is fine) and simpler (e.g. instead of manually going through the preferences and editing things every time just importing some file or something like that).

How do I do this more robustly/automatically?

cross: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/5935107638546-How-does-one-share-general-pycharm-setting-from-previous-pycharm-set-up-

Answer (score 1):

In pycharm you have to go to the menu:

File -> Manage IDE setting -> Export Settings -> Select desired options

Send the file to the new laptop then:

File -> Manage IDE setting -> Import Settings

Answer (score 0):

If exporting the settings and importing the settings works for you as Lucas mentioned, that's the way to go.

For completeness, PyCharm also has a [Settings Repository](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/sharing-your-ide-settings.html) which has some use cases, but it sounds like the effort probably isn't worth it for you. Also I tried using it 4 years ago as detailed in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45175404/how-to-setup-pycharm-settings-repository), but it had a-lot of issues at the time and I'm not sure if they've gotten any better