# How to share deployment configurations between different projects in PyCharm automatically?

Tags: pycharm, jetbrains-ide

The only way I can see to do this is to manually write the fields all over again with the `+` sign.

[image]

Surely PyCharm is storing this deployment data somewhere and I can just load the deploymen data again, right? How do I share this info btw projects?

---

Related:

- issue tracker: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-58203?_ga=2.129241801.4753629.1676677449-544835105.1676677449 and https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-40680/Allow-reusing-a-single-remote-interpreter-in-multiple-project
- other related sharing config info in pycharm:

  - [How does one share general pycharm setting from previous pycharm set up?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72520278/how-does-one-share-general-pycharm-setting-from-previous-pycharm-set-up)
  - [How do I get my settings from PyCharm in a file so not to lose them when updating PyCharm or creating a new Project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71025335/how-do-i-get-my-settings-from-pycharm-in-a-file-so-not-to-lose-them-when-updatin)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pycharm doesn't recognize file or folder with remote interpreter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73947300/pycharm-doesnt-recognize-file-or-folder-with-remote-interpreter) This is truly annoying. In the linked answer I show how to make a stable configuration that bypasses this pycharm bug. It is a hassle, but at least then you don't have to reconfigure every single time.

Answer (score 0):

Ok tbh I want to avoid passing file settings around because in the past it didn't work well. I assume PyCharm is buggy when managing those manually (in my experience at least).

Luckly there is a visible only for this project check box one can unclick for deployment settings. See picture:

[image]

There is another one in the SSH configuration:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is super painful feature that simply does not work well and it is not designed well. I like pycharm, and paying for it, but it is a bit bloated, and for remote development ssh deployments multiple projects just never works ...
Sad that everything else takes a precedence over issues like this...

Comment: curious, did you see my answer? what do you think? (btw, your answer is more a comment, so I'd put it in the comments of the question)